# How to use fragment_main.xml in layout-land folder?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have created simple application and it automatically generated **activity_main.xml** and **frgmented_main.xml** files.

I created new folder "**layout-land**"and added under "**res**" folder (layout and layout-res folders are in same level). Then I created another **fragmented_main.xml** file under **layout-land** folder  with same id and other stuff.

But the problem app is working perfectly for portrait orientation. but landscape orientation it stopped suddenly. I have no idea why. Should I do something more to fix this issue. Please help me to solve this issue.

here the code of activity_main.xml and fragmented_main.xml files.

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ds.mali.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

fragmented_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    tools:context="com.ds.mali.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Count is 0"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:onClick="addOne"
        android:text="Add One" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:onClick="subOne"
        android:text="Substract One" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here frgmaned_main.xml in layout-land folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ds.mali.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Count is 0"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:onClick="addOne"
            android:text="Add One" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:onClick="subOne"
            android:text="Substract One" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Welcome to landscape View " />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add `fragmented_main.xml` in `layout-land` as well as `layout-port` folder, this will solve your problem. also if possible post the stack trace to know the exact cause

Comment: I created layout-land folder and added fragmented_main.xml file.. then portrait version also does not work. so how can solve it

Comment: now only logcat stack trace tell us the exact cause. so post your logcat stack trace in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in activity tag

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

for eg :

```
  <activity
            android:name="com.world.nanomap.PathGoogleMapActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="Route Map" >
        </activity>
```

Comment: I am new to Programming. Where Can I found Activity Tag ?

Comment: Thank you.. Problem solved.. I will select this as best answer after 2 minutes